# classic asp website very slow in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

Asp pages load very slow in IIS 7.5 waiting from localhost and the same pages work well in IIS 6 and 
Can anyone share the solution if you have the same issue?

Comment: Can you add any more detail - what do your pages do?

Comment: asp pages retrieve and displays the data from SQL server 2005.

Comment: The database connection is possibly where the problem lies, see http://forums.iis.net/t/1156349.aspx.  Also, could you post your connection string

Comment: Thanks John for your quick response.Connection string is as "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Sever\XX;Initial Catalog=XX;Integrated Security=SSPI".Finally I am able to figure the issue that made the asp slow was the use of static cursor as oRS.open qry, oConn, 1, 2.After changing it forwardonly cursor with readonly locking as oRS.open  qry, oConn, 0,1  the pages worked like a charm.

Comment: You should post that as the answer. You're encouraged to do that on SO where appropriate - someone else might have the same issue in the future

Answer (score 0):

slowness was caused by use of static cursor as oRS.open qry, oConn, 1, 2.After changing it forwardonly cursor with readonly locking as oRS.open qry, oConn, 0,1 the pages much better.

See the for the details for similar issue resolved:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/50122f99-df96-424f-ae41-298a89c1135f/asp-code-recordset-too-slow-on-sql-server-2005?forum=sqldataaccess